# c# vb notifyicon disable hide configure option

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, winapi, user-controls

How do I get rid of the configure icon shown in attached screenshot ?

It opens up the windows taskbar area icon configure window where you config all the

icons shown in the taskbar.

Cannot find any property to disable this.

What is this called so I can google for this ? Nothing on msdn. thanks
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an OS native feature.

You cannot get rid of it.

Comment: thanks. Hopefully some win api expert will crack this and give us a way to do this via .net using unmanaged code...

Comment: No.  Windows does not give you any control over this.